# Is it possible to embed Google Navigation in an Android app?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps

I have an app which opens Google Maps from where the user is likely to start the Google Navigation from point A to B. Is it possible to open Google Maps and therefore Google Navigation only in specific proportion of the screen and display some additional (but minimal) information from my app next to the navigation?

I am thinking of something like this:

[image]

Additionally, is it possible to receive a broadcast when during the Google Navigation the user has arrived to her destination?

I know it is a bit far fetched, but maybe there are some ideas.

Comment: It's not possible but you can do this by using Here Maps.

Comment: I don't think it is possible in real time, but you can give or use Direction API as Gaurav has pointed out. Kindly check this [Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions) to check "c.Restrictions on your Maps API Implementations. iii.No navigation. You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control."

Comment: No, it is not possible to use Google Navigation.
But you can use other options:
Skobbler Maps: http://developer.skobbler.com
HERE Maps: https://developer.here.com (Paid)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are still interested in knowing about this after 2 years.
Short answer: Yes (with a but).

If you are asking about displaying a full Navigation experience with turn by turn instructions, a puck, routines on Google Maps, then the answer is: **It's illegal to do it without Google's permission**. If you look at the Lyft app for drivers, they do have a full navigation experience on top of Google Maps because they partnered with them. So, it's possible, but requires direct communication with Google engineers.

For a workaround, you could show an embed Google Maps view in your apps, and show Markers, Polylines. They also have these APIs to get directions from one place to the other one. For example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood4&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>
```

NOTE: Fees will apply when using these APIs. Check [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) for more details about the workaround.

Answer (score 5):

You can but you need to contact google personally this is google explanations about this subject and the contract page specially for your request https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/ridesharing/

Answer (score 2):

Not directly from Google map's navigation . But you can create your own by using 
Direction API.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start#sample-request

Answer (score -1):

yes ,
you can use point an geography point by polygone and line canvas for routing the path between two point on google map.

for more reference reffer this [Link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/).